# Easiest way to serve different content from the same link based of user agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cdn

I am current using an Amazon EC2 server to perform a GET on a url that comes in, read the ID in the the url (?id=XXXXX) and display and image based on the ID.

I then read the user agent and if it's mobile display one image, if it's desktop display another image. This could also be split as android vs iphone, or other parameters.

My question is, is there another way other than a EC2 server to do this? Is it possible to do this with a CDN that can pick the appropriate file?

Answer (score -1):

Can do with CloudFront, amazons CDN:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-user-agent-header

Comment: Cloudfront can forward additional information to the origin server so that the server can vary the response based on the desktop/mobile/tablet conclusion that Cloudfront makes... but Cloudfront does not make decisions about which content variant should be returned.  That's still done by the web server.

Comment: Right... and the question was whether this could be done by the CDN *without* the server.

Comment: thanks for the debate guys. yeah i want to be able to drop the server but i really don't think i'll be able to. it just adds extra cost and needs to be expandable to handle load at peak times which I had hoped to offload onto a CDN

Comment: The CDN will take load off your server. It caches the files retrieved from your server. If you want to get rid of the server alltogether you could move the decision what files to load to the client side, store the files with different names on S3 and use that as the origin for CloudFront.